# Ros Control: VelocityJointInterface and PositionJointInterface in one yaml

Tags: control, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

i am currently trying to build a simple car model from scratch.
So far my URDF comes along pretty good and my ROS Node also publishes data to the correct ros Node.

Lately i have tried to swich from all EffortJointInterface/PositionJointCtrlr EffortJointCtrlr to:

2x VelocityJointInterface/VelocityJointCtrlr for the "Engine" of my wheels
and
2x PositionJointInterface/PositionJointCtrlr for the Steering of my wheels.

But now i am only able to ctrl the position of my front wheels which are meant for steering and don't get any Velocity to my Rear Axle for forward motion.

!All ctrlr are in a running state, which makes it even stranger!

Do i need to lood the Hardware Interfaces separetly? Does anybody have experiece when working with different Ctrlr and Interfaces on the same model? I possible i want to avoid implementing my own interfaces.

Help is very much appreciated!
Franzisdrak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14419/ros-control:-velocityjointinterface-and-positionjointinterface-in-one-yaml/) by [Franzisdrak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2821/franzisdrak/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Fixed the error. I forgot to change the Interfaces in my urdf.

---

Originally posted by [Franzisdrak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2821/franzisdrak/) with karma: 43 on 2016-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Coach Allen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/22714/coach-allen/) on 2020-01-28**:
What would be nice, is to see the actual code. Us new guys finding you had the same problem, and not seeing how you fixed doesn't do much.